# Adding html inside function

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce

I need to add a symbol (→) inside a function. The function is supposed to display a product tag on the woocommerce single product page and link back to the specific tag archive. the last part of the function is

```
            echo '<h2><a href="'.esc_url($link).'" title="'.$text.'" class="" '.$term->slug.'">'.$text.'</a></h2>';
```

and I need the arrow to be displayed righ after the term slug. How do I insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as a html entity `&rarr;`

```
echo '<h2><a href="'.esc_url($link).'" title="'.$text.'" class="" '.$term->slug.'>&rarr;'.$text.'</a></h2>';
```

Hope I understand it correctly "displayed righ after the term slug" that you want it displayed before the text.

Here's the entity table for future references: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp

Comment: Thanks but I need it right after the text, not before. So this would be correct I assume: echo '<h2><a href="'.esc_url($link).'" title="'.$text.'" class="" '.$term->slug.'>'.$text.'&nbsp;&rarr;</a></h2>';    }